# Microsoft-Cognitive error 429 neither caused by frequency nor size

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We tried to use Microsoft-Cognitive Text to Speech service, and kept hitting 429 randomly. 
We found out the more characters (more than around 1700) the document contains, the more possibilities it became to hit 429.

However, our document, which contains 1700 characters, is far less than the limit for request size (4,194,304 bytes).
Also, it's single request. Shouldn't have the frequency issue. (The REST API request are limited to 25 per 5 seconds)